# Php calculate number of days between two date time format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a two days i want to get number of days between these two dates

```
$a = 25:10:2018 04:10 AM;
$b = 26:10:2018 04:10 PM;
```

My expected result is:

```
$result = 1.5 days;
```

calculate based on time

Answer (score -1):

I cannot add a comment but heres my 2 cents, 
    `$a = ('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $b = ('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $d1 = new DateTime($a);
    $d2 = new DateTime($b);`

```
$result = $d1->diff($d2);

//put your format in date format
$diff = $result->format("%D %H:%i:%s");
```

Hope this works for you...